# Forcing merge commits with jgitflow-gradle-plugin

Tags: git-merge, git-flow

Can I make `jgitflow-gradle-plugin` to create always a merge commit when I complete a feature (i.e. when I call task featureFinish)? I would like to avoid fast-forward merge of a feature branch to the develop branch.

When using Maven plugin `jgitflow-maven-plugin`, I can prevent fast-forward merging by the plugin property `suppressFastForward`. I am looking for analogous behavior with Gradle plugin `jgitflow-gradle-plugin`.

I have tried to set Git property `merge.ff` to `false` but it does not help.